# Who should I run slapindex as? Both root and openldap users seem unadvisable

Tags: openldap, slapd

I am following [these instructions](http://techpubs.spinlocksolutions.com/dklar/ldap.html) to install OpenLDAP on Debian 6.0.

The instructions tell me to run `slapindex` as root, but it sounds like Debian does not like the idea:

```
WARNING!
Runnig as root!
There's a fair chance slapd will fail to start.
Check file permissions!
```

Google leads me to a [discussion](http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-10737932-configuration-openldap-sous-debian) that suggests running `slapindex` as `openldap`. I find it strange as `slapindex` is not in the $PATH of `openldap`.

Which user should I run `slapindex` as?
If not `root`, why is `slapindex` in `/usr/sbin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can use both `root` and `openldap` as user running `slapindex`, but if you do it as root, please don't forget to change the OpenLDAP data directory permissions back to `openldap:openldap` if you do so. For example,

```
chown -R openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap/
```

Why `slapindex` is under `/usr/sbin`, I don't know. Perhaps because it is a very powerful and potentially dangerous tool which should be used those capable of being root, anyway.

Comment: It's probably in /usr/sbin because it is an administrative tool that requires specific permissions (though not necessarily root, obviously) to run.  Displaying it in the hypothetical list of "user" commands, such as with tab completion in bash, would be silly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about `/var/lib/ldap`. I accidentally ran `slapd` in debug mode as `root` and it stole all the file permissions away from the `openldap` user. A service restart failed due to `err 13` and told me to restore from backup. `chown` back to `openldap` for the files in `/var/lib/ldap` fixed me all up.

Answer (score 1):

> If not root, why is slapindex in /usr/sbin?

According to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf) (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) /usr/sbin are used for Non-essential system binaries, e.g., daemons for various network-services.

On CentOS, after executing slapindex as root you should change owner of the index in /var/lib/ldap to the ldap user, which is by default ldap. You could try to use su instead

```
# su - <ldap_user> -s /bin/bash /usr/sbin/slapindex
```